# module not found issue reactjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redux

I'm getting module not found issue and not sure what I am missing

`./src/reducers/index.js
Module not found: Can't resolve './authReducer' in '/Users/guest/Desktop/MERN_APP/app/client/src/reducers'`

Here is the index.js

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import authReducer from "./authReducer";
import errorReducer from "./errorReducer";
export default combineReducers({
  auth: authReducer,
  errors: errorReducer
});
```

Here is the authReducer.js

```
import { SET_CURRENT_USER, USER_LOADING } from "../actions/types";

const isEmpty = require("is-empty");

const initialState = {
  isAuthenticated: false,
  user: {},
  loading: false
};

export default function(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_CURRENT_USER:
      return {
        ...state,
        isAuthenticated: !isEmpty(action.payload),
        user: action.payload
      };
    case USER_LOADING:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: true
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Here is store.js this is where root reducer is being called

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from "redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import rootReducer from "./reducers";
const initialState = {};
const middleware = [thunk];
const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  initialState,
  compose(
    applyMiddleware(...middleware),
    window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
  )
);
export default store;
```

The file structure looks like this

`\client
    store.js
   \reducers
      authReducer.js
      index.js`

The file structure should make the module accessible but not sure if that is causing the problem.

Comment: Are the `index.js` and the `authReducer.js` in same directory?

Comment: yes they are in same directory

Comment: does the code run without error when you comment out `import authReducer from "./authReducer";` and ` auth: authReducer,`

Comment: nope I am getting `./src/reducers/index.js
Module not found: Can't resolve './errorReducer' in '/Users/guest/MERN_APP/app/client/src/reducers'`  when I comment out `import ./authReducer` and `auth:authreducer` from  index.js